# Type-hinting named array keys in Eclipse for PHP like $_SERVER?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I don't know if this is functionality of PHPDoc, or build into PHP Development Tools in Eclipse, but when I type:

```
$_SERVER['']
```

It begins to auto-complete to:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN']
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
```

Etc. So I'm getting a Guzzle Model back from AWS S3, and I want to type-hint what's in the result array that I'm returning:

```
/* @var $result['Expiration'] string */
/* @var $result['ETag'] string */
/* @var $result['ServerSideEncryption'] string */
/* @var $result['VersionId'] string */
/* @var $result['SSECustomerAlgorithm'] string */
/* @var $result['SSECustomerKeyMD5'] string */
/* @var $result['RequestId'] string */
/* @var $result['ObjectURL'] string */
$result = $s3->uploadFile(...);
return $result;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Simply answer: No. $_SERVER structure is hardcoded in PDT.

You can create enhancement request on PDT bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT

PSR-5 introduce ability to describe array structure via @typedef, but it's still in draft: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md